# Clicking on a non-visible button is Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a button that is only visible when hovering over it.
move_to_element doesn't seem to work and I get this error when trying to click `ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible`

My code is:

```
full_screen_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="grid"]/div[2]/div[1]/article/div[3]/a')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(full_screen_elem)
hover.perform()
full_screen_elem.click()
```

I've also tried this:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', full_screen_elem)
```

But it also doesn't work.
What else can I try?

Comment: can you share the page url as well?

Comment: @talon Find an element which is visible and near this hidden element. Find this visible element and using actions move to this. Then use a judgement of the amount of pixels you need to move to hover element. Add this to the actions chain to move the fixed amount. This should make this visible and then you can click.

Answer (score 2):

Try and make it visible using Javascript.
I assume the style-attribute of your element is set to hidden. You must set this to visible.
You can do this as following:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("element").style.visibility = "visible";);
```

Then you can interact with the element.
Be sure to double check the syntax from above script because I am a little rusty :)

Comment: Thanks, although it wasn't the hidden style but your answer got me to look what changed when I hover the mouse. I saw that 'visible' was added to the class. So, I used `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("class","qv-object-nav inline visible");', full_screen_elem)` and got the trick.